# UserTransaction with DataSource.getConnection() and DataSourceUtils.getConnection

Tags: java, transactions, datasource, spring-transactions

```
static void clean() throws Exception {
  final UserTransaction tx = InitialContext.doLookup("UserTransaction");
  tx.begin();

  try {
    final DataSource ds = InitialContext.doLookup(Databases.ADMIN);
    Connection connection = ds.getConnection();//line 1
    connection = ds.getConnection(); //line 2- call again for testing purpose
    PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("xxxxxxx sql script");
    st.executeUpdate();
    st.close();
    connection.close();
    tx.commit();
  } finally {
    if (tx.getStatus() == Status.STATUS_ACTIVE) {
      tx.rollback();
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to compare `DataSource.getConnection()` and `DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSource)`, according to the Javadoc, the first one always get a new connection and second one always get a current connection that bind to the active `UserTransaction` (in current thread).

I saw the sample code above, I don't understand how come the example using `DataSource.getConnection`, which based on my understanding, we should always use `DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSource)` instead of other, because we want to commit the whole chunk of scripts in a connection instead of having more than one connection. (correct me if I am wrong)

I don't understand why, so I added a duplicated line to test (line 2), can anyone explain how this thing work in background if there is without line 2 and with line 2? What is the difference?

***Edited***

Based on the Javadoc, `DataSource.getConnection()` is not even able to attach the connection to the active `Usertransaction`, how does the `UserTransaction` internally set the connection's `autoCommit(false)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar question, which already answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823693/java-more-than-one-db-connection-in-usertransaction).

As long as the calling is inside transaction context and we are using `DataSource` to obtain the connection, it is smart enough to always return the only active connection. I think it is related to the implementation of the transaction manager and the `DataSource`, which for my case, both I have fetched from Weblogic via JNDI.